# hyperlink issue in Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I'm a neophyte programmer.  I've built a couple of sites with Joomla, and not had any problems. The site I'm working on now has an important hyperlink to a manufacturer's site, and I'm getting an error message:

> This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.&n=125958">

The link is to a third party site, and does have my email embedded in it, so that I get credit for sales derived from that link. The link works fine in a plain html page, but not in Joomla.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Steven

Answer (score 0):

Joomla core comes with email obfuscation plugins with defaults to enabled.  The purpose of which is to prevent spiders from being able to extract emails embedded in your site.  From administrator dashboard navigate to Extensions > Plugins Manager.  Search for and disable the Content - Email Cloaking plugins and test to see if the links works properly.

Again, this will expose any embedded email addresses in your site to scripts crawling for email addresses.  If this is the only email which would be presented in plain text as a result then the risk is limited considering the feature is hindering your minimization capabilities.